# Temporarily storing dynamic JSP pages as HTML to improve performance and lower resources

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7

We are working on a Spring MVC web application (running in Tomcat 7) and currently we are experiencing moderate load on the website. The main resource that has to be raised from time to time is RAM due to increasing number of users.

Some of our JSPs are pretty complex, but on the other hand they aren't changing very often. I was wondering if there is a library or some kind of cache system, which would store generated HTML that was generated from JSP for a recent page visitor and serve the next user as a static content. This would lower the stress on our application server (CPU, RAM).

My idea is that it should function like some kind of server-side cache so we could set how long the page should be cached as HTML and delete that cache if necessary. Tomcat would user HTML version if available or simply use classic JSP if needed (and generate HTML after that). So far I haven't found anything like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: `The main resource that has to be raised from time to time is RAM`. Sounds like a memory leak; perharps you should focus on correcting that as a first step.

Comment: It's not exactly what your looking for, but it may helps http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/

Comment: @SJuan76, indeed memory leaks are problematic, but at the moment we believe we are not experiencing them. The goal is simply to further reduce resources needed per single user.

Comment: So, these JSP's are complex but have absolutely no dynamic content on them at all? They are generated once and then always return the same thing, regardless of who is logged in?

Comment: Use HTTP caching. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html

Comment: @DaveHowes, the pages are dynamic, but do not change very often. For example, take public profile on LinkedIn.com. The data is changed only now and then when the user changes his profile. But in the time between two changes the server is generating identical pages for every page visitor. That seems a waste of CPU to me. I hope I made things clearer.

Comment: @BhashitParikh, HTTP caching is great, when one user fetches the same page multiple times. But when 10.000 users open the same page in one minute interval, the server runs JSP generation 10.000 times, but in the end, serves the same page to all(if it hasn't changed in that minute). I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Is it possible to identify that the data that is being presented needs to be refreshed? If it is, could you consider creating and caching a model object that the jsp just renders? Cache the model object against the user somehow ( session / database / .... ). If the data does not need refreshing, render the cached model. If it does need refreshing, rebuild the model, cache it, and render it?

Answer (score 0):

JSP are dynamic by nature. A JSP page is first compiled into a Servlet and then up to answer client requests and generate HTML content to the browser. So, you have to consider your design. If you are using JSP to generate dynamic content, maybe this specific page is not supposed to be cached.

Otherwise, if you know that the content is really static, make it a simple HTML (or .xhtml) page, skipping JSP-Servlet compilation process. You can still create a javax.servlet.Filter to generate cache headers (cache-control, expires, etc...) for these specific static resources.

If you are using Tomcat, you can even create a  acting as a request processing filter
as a general purpose caching filter for static resources on the server.

Comment: Our pages are dynamic, but do not change very often. For example, take public profile on LinkedIn.com. The data is changed only now and then when the user changes his profile. But in the time between two changes the server is generating identical pages for every page visitor. That seems a waste of CPU to me. I hope I made things clearer.

Comment: Static resources are already handled with another server which serves only static content.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a reverse proxy in front of your Tomcat(s), consider setting up Varnish, and have it cache those particular JSPs (among other things). But be sure to not cache anything sensitive (user-specific). See https://www.varnish-cache.org/.